# How to modell this shape?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to modell the shape on this image.

[image]

But as you can see the middle part on the image is more narrow than what would come out of the boolean operation in my modell. How do can I modell the shape on the picture above?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution, maybe there is a simpler one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer … tried to create it using your method but was not able to … Would be helpful also for others to maybe share your bevel tool settings.

Comment: when you've created you 3 vertex circle, select all in Edit mode, then shift ctrl B, then pull. Now, on the bottom of the Tools panel (on the left of the 3D View), you have a series of parameters: the Amount depends on the size of you circle, so for the moment choose something that will not give any overlap. Segments: choose 8. Profile: choose 0.15 so that it will be concave. It should work, or tell me where it doesn't work   ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe deform one of the circles with proportional editing and paste him to the positions you want him.

I'm sure there is a more precise way of doing this but this came first in my mind